# Using semaphore in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, semaphore

Hi I am trying to use `Semaphore` in my application. I have declared like this.

```
class MyThread
{
    public Thread Thrd;

    static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(2, 2);
    public MyThread(string name)
    {
        Thrd = new Thread(this.Run);
        Thrd.Name = name;
        Thrd.Start();
    }
}
```

But I am not able to compile It's giving me this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Semaphore' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But I have already added the namespace  `using System.Threading;` I am able to using **Mutex**.
May be what was I am missing. There is any other reference need to add.? I am using **VS 2010**. Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semaphores were [introduced in .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)

System.Threading.dll was added in .NET 4.0 (though the namespace System.Threading has been around since v1). Maybe your project includes an older version of System.Threading.

It is a frequently asked question [The type or namespace '' does not exist in the class or namespace '' (are you missing an assembly reference?)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/04/29/why-did-i-receive-the-error-the-type-or-namespace-lt-namespace-name-gt-does-not-exist-in-the-class-or-namespace-lt-parent-namespace-gt-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference.aspx)

You need to add a reference in your project to an assembly where that namespace is defined or you are missing an using statement despite you stating that you are using System.Threading.

Comment: It is defined in `System.dll` and obviously he is using that. He also mentioned it's .NET framework 4.

Comment: @oleksii: Not necessarily. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/545b1628-23fb-4d69-ab42-09ed008e3b46/

and System.Threading.dll was added in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

```
 .NET Framework
 Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
.NET Framework Client Profile
 Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
 Portable Class Library
 Supported in: Portable Class Library
 .NET for Windows Store apps
 Supported in: Windows 8
```

May you need another version of framework

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you add 4.0 version to get the appropriate reference for Semaphore class.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles for me

```
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class MyThread
    {
        static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(2, 2);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }
}
```

- VS 2010
- .NET 4.0
- Single reference to `System.dll` *v4.0.0.0, Runtime version v4.0.30319, Located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll*