# The type or namespace 'Semaphore Slim could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore

Having similar issue to this

[using semaphore in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658318/using-semaphore-in-c-sharp)

I have determined that I have .NET 4.6.4 Preview or greater on my machine.

So what gives?
My understanding is that System.Threading contains the SempahoreSlim class.

I am using source code from this example
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/488668/csharp-tcp-server

Just a partial code listing (first 50 lines of TcpServer)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace tcpServer
{
    public delegate void tcpServerConnectionChanged(TcpServerConnection connection);
    public delegate void tcpServerError(TcpServer server, Exception e);

    public partial class TcpServer : Component
    {
        private List<TcpServerConnection> connections;
        private TcpListener listener;

        private Thread listenThread;
        private Thread sendThread;

        private bool m_isOpen;

        private int m_port;
        private int m_maxSendAttempts;
        private int m_idleTime;
        private int m_maxCallbackThreads;
        private int m_verifyConnectionInterval;
        private Encoding m_encoding;

        private SemaphoreSlim sem;


        private bool waiting;
```

Comment: Have you checked the target framework of your project? Yout can do this in visual studio by right clicking on the project and seleting properties. There should be a box there telling you your traget framework, check that this is higher than or equal to .NET 3

Comment: This is a Unity C# project. If I open the source project in VS I don't see the error and project properties shows I am targeting .Net framework 4. So I guess my question is more to do with the way Unity handles .net classes. Confused whether I should be trying to fix this WITHIN VS in the Solution explorer or...?

Comment: Ah right okay I don't have any experience in Unity. So what exactly is the problem, are you compiling and developing outside of VS?

Comment: ok I think the answer is unfortunately Unity ONLY supports .Net 2. Though there was a way to incorporate .Net 4 classes in Unity, apparently not.